# Problems with a self joining full outer join query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has both cost and revenue budget rows in one table aaPMBudget for a given project and it's various components.

There is a column call Type which can be 'E' for cost and 'I' for revenue. 
What I want to do is to combine them on the first 6 key fields showing one row for both cost and revenue if the key fields match, a single row for cost if there is no matching revenue and a single row for revenue if there is no cost.

I have given the data, the attempt I've made (The result I get). For some reason which I'm sure is obvious the 'I' rows on the right side of the full outer join are excluded. I have also included the result I want. For various reasons I'd really like to use a full outer join to achieve this

```
SET Nocount ON
DROP TABLE aaPMBudget

CREATE TABLE [aaPMBudget](
    [CompanyID]      [int] NOT NULL,  [ProjectID]      [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectTaskID]  [int] NOT NULL,  [CostcodeID]     [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,  [InventoryID]    [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type]           [char](1)        NOT NULL,
    [CuryAmount]     [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO [aaPMBudget] (CompanyID, ProjectID, ProjectTaskID, CostCodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount) Values (2,3419,2060,690,60,10039,'I',1.00)
INSERT INTO [aaPMBudget] (CompanyID, ProjectID, ProjectTaskID, CostCodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount) Values (2,3419,2060,859,60,10039,'E',3.00)
INSERT INTO [aaPMBudget] (CompanyID, ProjectID, ProjectTaskID, CostCodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount) Values (2,3419,2060,859,60,10039,'I',2.00)
INSERT INTO [aaPMBudget] (CompanyID, ProjectID, ProjectTaskID, CostCodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount) Values (2,3419,2060,862,78,10039,'E',4.00)
INSERT INTO [aaPMBudget] (CompanyID, ProjectID, ProjectTaskID, CostCodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount) Values (2,3419,2061,862,60,10039,'I',5.00)
```

The result I want:

[image: The result I want]

The result I get with the full outer join query below:

[image: The result I get with the full outer join query below]

```
SELECT 'The result I get' as Dataset, 
       a.ProjectID, b.ProjectID,
       a.ProjectTaskID, b.ProjectTaskID,
       a.CostcodeID, b.CostcodeID,
       a.AccountGroupID, b.AccountGroupID,
       a.InventoryID, b.InventoryID,
       a.Type, b.Type,
       a.CuryAmount as RevenueBudget,
       b.CuryAmount as CostBudget
FROM   aaPMBudget a
  FULL OUTER JOIN aaPMBudget b ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID 
                            and a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID 
                            and a.ProjectTaskID = b.ProjectTaskID
                            and a.CostcodeID = b.CostcodeID 
                            and a.AccountGroupID = b.AccountGroupID 
                            and a.InventoryID = b.InventoryID 
                            and b.Type = 'I' 
WHERE a.Type = 'E'
```

Comment: Seems like overkill. Why not just group by your key columns and conditionally sum (did you leave that part out?)  or display the revenue and cost values?

Comment: Also note that your where clause affects the full outer join logic and converts it into a typical left join. To achieve the desired goal, you need to move that logic into the join (e.g., and b.Type = I and a.Type = 'E'). However, that approach has an assumption that you might regret later (uniqueness of your joining columns) which is avoided (mitigated?) with the aggregation approach.

Comment: I did try and go down that route but it's the "you need to move that logic into the join (e.g., and b.Type = I and a.Type = 'E')" that tripped me up. I can see where to add the "and b.Type = 'I'" but how to add the "and a.Type = 'E'" if not put into the where clause. May be right after the "and b.Type = 'I' in the full outer join ? Let me try that. No that was not it........

Comment: The problem here is that I really want to use a full outer join since there is a large number of other fields I need to read and I'd rather not group by all of them since I'm sure there will be differences between the I and the E records and that will result in two result rows. In the example I just list the key fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code-

```
select 
CompanyID,
[ProjectID],
[ProjectTaskID],
[CostcodeID],
[AccountGroupID],
[InventoryID],
MIN([Type]) Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'E' THEN [CuryAmount] ELSE 0 END) AS CostBudget,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'I' THEN [CuryAmount] ELSE 0 END) AS RevBudget
from aaPMBudget
group by CompanyID,[ProjectID],[ProjectTaskID],[CostcodeID],[AccountGroupID],[InventoryID]
order by 5
```

Output will be-

```
CompanyID   ProjectID   ProjectTaskID   CostcodeID  AccountGroupID  InventoryID Type    CostBudget  RevBudget
2           3419        2060            690         60              10039       I       0.0000      1.0000
2           3419        2060            859         60              10039       E       3.0000      2.0000
2           3419        2061            862         60              10039       I       0.0000      5.0000
2           3419        2060            862         78              10039       E       4.0000      0.0000
```

Comment: For the data given this solution works perfectly thank you. I however becomes cumbersome when you have an additional 20-30 fields to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT ISNULL(C.CompanyID, R.CompanyID) AS CompanyID, ISNULL(C.ProjectID,R.ProjectID) ProjectID,  ISNULL(C.ProjectTaskID,R.ProjectTaskID) ProjectTaskID,  ISNULL(C.CostcodeID,R.CostcodeID) CostcodeID, ISNULL(C.AccountGroupID, R.AccountGroupID) AccountGroupID, ISNULL(C.InventoryID, R.InventoryID) InventoryID, C.Type, R.Type,RevenueBudget,CostBudget
FROM 
    (SELECT CompanyID, ProjectID,  ProjectTaskID,  CostcodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount as CostBudget
    FROM   aaPMBudget WHERE Type = 'E') C
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT CompanyID, ProjectID,  ProjectTaskID,  CostcodeID, AccountGroupID, InventoryID, Type, CuryAmount as RevenueBudget
    FROM   aaPMBudget WHERE Type = 'I') R
ON C.CompanyID = R. CompanyID AND C.ProjectID = R.ProjectID AND C.ProjectTaskID = R.ProjectTaskID 
    AND C.CostcodeID = R.CostcodeID AND C.AccountGroupID = R.AccountGroupID AND C.InventoryID = R.InventoryID
```